# Recharts - How to don't interpolate the values Area Chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

Hi I'm facing a problem with the Recharts library.

My data set rendered as **green** and **light blue** stacked Area chart elements ends on Xaxis value = 03, but the Area chart element is interpolated for the Xaxis values 03 - 04.

Do you know how I can manage to just end these area charts elements on 03 (just remove the part rendered in the red triangle).

I tried to providing 0 and null values and removing data keys for the data entries where is no relevant data

Example of a single Area chart element:

```
<Area
  dataKey="claims_closed_volume"
  stackId="1"
  fill="#52C41A"
/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding this correctly you will want to add the `XAxis` component as a **sibling** to your `Area` component. 
The `XAxis` component has a `domain` property with which you can define the range of values to be presented.

[XAxis | Recharts](http://recharts.org/en-US/api/XAxis) - Check out the docs!

Example code:

```
<AreaChart width={500) height={200} data={data}>
  <Area
    dataKey="claims_closed_volume"
    stackId="1"
    fill="#52C41A"
  />
  <XAxis type="number" domain={[0, 3]} />
</AreaChart>
```

Comment: Right, solution sounds reasonable, but unfortunately Recharts doesn't work this way. XAxis cannot be a child component of the Area component. XAxis relates to the whole data set not a single type of the data set so there is no option to separate it and limit the rendered data to the provided domain range.

Comment: My apologies friend! I mistook that for the `AreaChart` component, and in my haste to help answer your question I have brought shame on my entire family. I will continue researching this to appease the SO gods...
Can you add the `XAxis` component as a **Sibling** to the area component?